# How to get specific items with requests

Tags: python

I'm trying to get just one currency with the exchangerate-api

here is what I tried:

```
import requests

url = 'https://v6.exchangerate- 
api.com/v6/API-KEY/latest/EUR'

response = requests.get(url, params={"conversion_rates": "BGN"})
data = response.json()

print(data)
```

I just want to get a specific one and only its rate against EUR forex BGN = 0,51 EUR

Comment: `url = 'https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/API-KEY/pair/EUR/BGN'`? Documentation here: https://www.exchangerate-api.com/docs/pair-conversion-requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know which specific rate you want, do

```
rate = data["conversion_rates"]["BGN"]
print(1./rate)
```

Comment: Is there a way to lower the decimal number that it outputs?

Comment: `print("{:.2f}".format(1./rate))` should work for 2 decimals.